# Exposing variables to a lambda returned from within defun

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm attempting to attach a key handler such that a wrapper function is first executed that checks whether a library has been loaded and, if not, loads it before finally executing the intended function.

The idea is to be able to do:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r")
                (run-or-load-f 'visual-regexp 'vr/replace))
```

Where `run-or-load-f` is:

```
(defmacro run-or-load-f (mode func)
  `(lambda()
     (interactive)
     (run-or-load mode func)))
```

The problem I'm having is that **I do not know how to expose `mode` and `func` in the lambda above**.  I'm not even sure I need a macro but it does seem that way.

For completion's sake, the function `run-or-load` above is very simply:

```
(defun run-or-load (mode func)
  (unless (fboundp mode)
    (load-library (symbol-name mode)))
  (call-interactively func))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your answer does **not** "*allow the lambda to act like a closure*".

To make the lambda act like a closure, turn on `lexical-binding` as a file-local variable in the first line of your file.  See the Elisp manual, node [Lexical Binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html).

What your answer, which uses backquote with comma, does is to **substitute** the values of those variables in place of the variables within the lambda. That is, it removes those free variables, replacing them by the values they have *at the time the lambda is constructed (evaluated)*.

The advantage of using a closure here is that the *variables are available when the function is invoked* (not just when it is defined). (If you don't need the variables at that time then this advantage disappears.)

If you had used `defun` instead of `defmacro` then another advantage of the closure is that the resulting function can be automatically byte-compiled when the file is compiled.

In contrast, with the backquoted lambda approach, the result at byte-compile time is just a list: `(lambda ...)`. There is no way for the compiler to know that you intend to always use that list as a function, so it is not compiled into a function - it is evaluated as a list each time the function is invoked. (Unless you explicitly call the byte compiler to compile it.)

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to use a different syntax when invoking `run-or-load`, which allows the lambda to act like a closure:

```
(defmacro run-or-load-f (mode func)
  `(lambda()
     (interactive)
     (run-or-load ,mode ,func)))
```